Prefer line wrap over wider row in Jetpack Compose
I'm creating an app in Jetpack Compose. In the start page I will have several cards in a FlowRow. The problem is that if the text in the card is long enough the card will expand in width instead of wrapping the text in several rows. How can I tell compose a base width for my card, to wrap the text if it is possible and the width is wider than the base and only make the card wider if it needs to.
    FlowRow(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit")
    } <-- This one should wrap
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Text("Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit")
    } <-- This one should widen
    }

